# SOLIDITY: Trying to get working Mapping/Struct for giving a "player" multiple "tickets", problem(s) with array

Tags: arrays, struct, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

Thanks in advance for getting here and trying to see my bad code.

So, I have some trouble on trying to "sell" tickets to people and give them the possibility to buy >=1.

Now, the problem, is that i can't associate an array of 6 numbers to the ticket.

What is wrong? Thanks!

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Lottery is Ownable {
    
   uint256 constant ticketprice = 1 ether;
   address  pool = addresshere;
   uint ID = 0;
   uint256 startinglottery;
   
   struct Picket { 
   uint ID;
   uint[6] ticket;
   }
   
   mapping (address => Picket) hope;
   address[] players;
   
    constructor() {
    startinglottery = 0;
    }
    
    
    function StartLottery() public onlyOwner {
    startinglottery = 1;  
    }
    
    function EndLottery() public onlyOwner {
        
    startinglottery = 0;
    }
    
    function BuyTicket(address _address) public payable {
        //check
        require(msg.value >= ticketprice, "not enought money!");
        require(startinglottery == 1, "lottery isn't started.");
        //pay
        payable(pool).transfer(msg.value);
        //do stuff
        Picket memory picket = hope[_address];
        picket.ID = ID;
        picket.ticket = [1,2,3,4,5]; //should be random with chainlink, but trying to understand the basic one.
        players.push(_address);
        ID++;
        
    }
    
    function getTicket(address _address) public view returns(uint, uint[6] memory) {
        return (hope[_address].ID, hope[_address].ticket);
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
picket.ticket = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Here you're trying to assign an array of 5 items to an array of 6 items. You need to explicitly define the 6th value - which is the default value of `0`.

Also, since you're passing hardcoded low values, the compiler incorrectly marks them as `uint8`. You need to cast at least the first one to `uint256` (or its alias `uint`) for the compiler to recognize the correct datatype.

```
picket.ticket = [uint256(1), 2, 3, 4, 5, 0];
```

Comment: Ok, array works in this way, but having problem with the getTicket() functions, it returns ID = 0 and array 0 0 0 0 0 0.

Comment: It's because you're assigning `0` ID on this line: `picket.ID = ID;` (the value of `ID` is 0)... And you're only accessing the `picket` in `memory`. If you wanted to store in storage, you need to redefine the `Picket memory picket` as `Picket storage picket`.